# Compare two tables, get sum based on date and decrement sum for next record

Tags: excel, vba

First table : Required quantity

```
  Ship From   Material   Req Date    Req Quantity   Fulfill(Y/N)?  
 ----------- ---------- ----------- -------------- --------------- 
         21   Mat1       7/1/2018              46                  
         21   Mat1       8/19/2018             33                  
         21   Mat1       9/2/2018              99                  
         21   Mat1       9/2/2018               4                  
        106   Mat1       9/16/2018             92                  
        106   Mat1       8/19/2018            126                  
        457   Mat2       8/19/2018            126                  
        457   Mat2       9/10/2018            126                  
        457   Mat2       9/10/2018            126                  
        457   Mat2       9/10/2018             24                  
        478   Mat2       9/2/2018              52                  
        478   Mat2       9/10/2018             73                  
        478   Mat2       9/10/2018             18                  
        478   Mat2       9/16/2018             30
```

Second Table : Available Inventory

```
  Ship From   Material   Inv Available Date   Available Qty  
 ----------- ---------- -------------------- --------------- 
         21   Mat1       6/15/2018                       46  
         21   Mat1       6/15/2018                       33  
         21   Mat1       7/2/2018                        99  
         21   Mat1       10/2/2018                        4  
        106   Mat1       10/16/2018                      92  
        106   Mat1       7/19/2018                      126  
        457   Mat2       8/19/2018                      126  
        457   Mat2       8/10/2018                      126  
        478   Mat2       9/16/2018                       30  
        478   Mat2       10/2/2018                       52
```

We need to check whether we have enough inventory(sum(Available qty)) in the second table on or before Inv available date and mark on table1 whether we can fulfill the order.

Please note we need to decrement sum of qty from table 2 for orders fulfilled on table 1.

I've the data in excel, can we write excel formula (vba) or pivot table to achieve this or I can load this into SQL.

I've 70k rows in table1 and 600k rows in table2.
I tried power query but couldn't achieve what I wanted.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note how much easier the data is to read when put through a proper tool like [ASCII Table Generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) However I still don't understand what you are trying to do.  What would we completed product look like, using the example data you provided?

Comment: @ashleedawg Thank you for formatting my post. I tried doing it in notepad but failed miserably. End product should have Fulfill column filled out on Table1. - As laid out in the below post, I need to know if my orders can be fulfilled by the required date.

Comment: You're welcome - I, too, posted ugly data, until I discovered that awesome [**website**](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/).

Answer (score 1):

Comparing aggregated total from 70K rows to 600K rows of related data is going to take some computing power no matter which method you choose but I feel that a simple SUMIFS vs SUMIFS is a viable option.

You are shipping 46 mat1s from 21 on 01-Jul but you have 79 in stock on that date so it can be fulfilled. Same with 19-Aug. However, on 02-Sep, you have orders of 99 and 4 but can only complete one of the orders due to depleted stock from previous shipments. The second order cannot be fulfilled until stock is replenished on 02-Oct. Likewise two orders of mat2 can be fulfilled from 457 but the third cannot. The first shipment of mat2 from 478 will be late and that reduces the avail qty so the second shipment cannot be made at all without additional inventory.

In E3 per supplied image,

```
=IF(SUMIFS(K:K, H:H, A3, I:I, B3, J:J, "<="&C3)>=SUMIFS(D$3:D3, A$3:A3, A3, B$3:B3, B3, C$3:C3, "<="&C3), "Y", "N")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Jeeped for this. I tried running this in excel and excel does not respond. Would it be faster in sql?

Comment: This works for a small dataset but crashes excel for a large dataset. How do I get around this? I'm working on building a sql query, no progress so far, any help please?

Comment: How does it "crash"?  Do you get an error, or what happens?  The first thing I'd suggest is to **reboot** your computer and try again.  @Jeeped's  formula should work fine on any size of dataset, so there's likely something else going on.  How big is this dataset, and are there other formula's in the file?

Comment: Inventory data is about 25Mb, Table1 is about 20Mb. I'm processing this in excel, it becomes unresponsive when I enter the formula on one cell and I've to end up killing the task from task manager.

Comment: You're not saving as xlsb and I hope you have 64 bit Office.

Comment: Unresponsive is not crashing; you are the one 'crashing' it with task manager. You're probably on 32 bit Office with limited ram.

Comment: I've 64bit excel & 16 Gb RAM. My processor is consumed whereas my memory consumption is 8 Gb when I run this. Does your formula keep track of the sum(Avl qty) consumed by Req_Qty?